# How to prevent redirection to home in production using Gatsby?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm linking from outside (let's say a social media) to a specific page of my website. When the user clicks, he can see the redirection for a second before behind redirected to the main page. But on the website, you can correctly access the page.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I'm using private navigation to emulate a new visitor coming.

Comment: Can you provide a sample link that you're seeing this behaviour on? And does this happen for a link that's shared anywhere? say, FB/insta/other etc.?

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**: the problem was with nginx and two conflicting configuration files...